# Permission denied when require() calls another PHP file

Tags: php, laravel, apache, require, httpd.conf

I use require() from a PHP file(**index.php**) inside Document Root of Apache server. The PHP file is failing execution. The error thrown in apache's error_log is below

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/root/new/test/public/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /root/new/test/public/index.php on line 24

The line 24 has

> require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

I have given 777 permission to **vendor** directory and even to the **/root/new/test** folder. But still the issue occurs.

The apache settings in httpd.conf is as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /root/new/test/public
    <Directory "/root/new/test/public">
           Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
            Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am i missing here?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have run `composer install` and it gives the below output

```
[root@localhost test]# composer install
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
@php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't install composer

```
composer install
```

After Install Composer give permission the public folder & storage

Comment: Updated the question with composer output .. The issue remains

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload files from your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/global.php",
    ]
},
```

Here my application will load /app/Helpers/global.php and it'll be available globally. It may require a `composer dumpautoload`.